# Parse json with square brackets

Tags: android, json, parsing

Im trying to Parse a json but i dont know how to Parse something like this?

{"max_current":["100","25"]}
- i want to get the max which is the 100 and the current which is the 25 please help me thanks.

Comment: @ JAC Can you post your code, so that it will be easy to solve.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
String jsonString = {"max_current":["100","25"]};

try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(JsonString);
        JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObj.getJSONArray("max_current");
        int max = jsonArray.getInt(0);
        int currnet = jsonArray.getInt(1);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjReq = new JsonObjectRequest(Method.GET,
                    yourwebserivce_Url, null,
                    new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {

                        @Override
                        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                            Log.d(TAG, response.toString());
                           JSONArray arr= response.getJSONArray("max_current");

            for(int i=0;i<arr.length();i++)
                            {
            JSONObject g=arr.getJSONObject(i);
            int max = g.getInt(0);
            int currnet = g.getInt(1);
                            }

            } catch (JSONException e) {

               e.printStackTrace();
                            }   
                        }
                    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                            VolleyLog.d(TAG, "Error: " + error.getMessage());
                            // hide the progress dialog

                        }
                    });

    // Adding request to request queue
    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjReq, tag_json_obj);
```